# Do I need to provide voltages higher than the battery's present voltage to further charge it?

Tags: voltage, battery-charging

Take for example currently my battery is at 25 Volts. I need to increase its voltages, to further charge it. Should I supply it with volts higher than 25?

P.S. I can format the question if it is not clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

Well, to push in charges into anything, you need a voltage difference. So, yes.

Generally: You usually don't charge batteries just by connecting them to an uncontrolled voltage source. The correct method for charging a battery depends fully on its type, its current charge status and usage scenario. But physically, whenever a battery is charged, the voltage applied externally must be higher than the battery voltage. Otherwise, you'd do nothing (external potential = battery potential, i.e. no current flows), or discharge it (external potential < battery potential, i.e. the battery provides your external "charger" with power, not the other way around).

This is a very basic consideration about what voltage is. Maybe you want to brush up your very electronics basics before charging batteries, since depending on their type, they can overheat, gas out (explosive hydrogen, for example), or simply catch fire or explode.

Comment: So perhaps the solar inverter internally increases the 24V from panels to higher voltages to charge batteries to 27V (floating voltages)?

Comment: Well, *something* will have to do that, yes, *as I already said in my answer*. Again, **you need a charging controller**.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to charge a battery, current has to flow into it, which means having a power source with a higher voltage than the battery has when off load.

However, normally we arrange things so that we use a current source, to provide a controlled current into the battery. The voltage this provides is 'whatever is necessary' to drive that current into the battery.